# Output at any location into the console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently making a Node.js application that needs to output a text at any location I want, for example at the top right corner.

I would know if there is a Node.js module to do that, like :

```
var the_module = require('the_module');
the_module.output(3, 3, "Hello world !");
```

Do you know one ?
Thanks by advance.

Comment: top right corner of what? what is `the_module`

Comment: Of the console, sorry

Comment: maybe the npm ansi module will help - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi

Comment: Hope this helps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/charm

Comment: Thanks that's working perfectly :) I didn't find these packages while searching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JaromandaX and @Vasan answered, the [ansi](https://npmjs.com/package/ansi) and [charm](https://npmjs.com/package/charm) packages can do this well. Thanks for your help !